# How to access elements from a list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am accessing the properties of an image collection in GEE. I have created an image collection and assigned it to the variable "collection". When accessing the date range I used the following syntax

```
//Create Image Collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
          .filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_PATH", 118))
          .filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_ROW", 56))
          .filterDate("2020-05-16", "2021-06-17");
Map.addLayer(collection)
Map.centerObject(collection, 9)
print("Collection: ", collection);

//Get date range
var dates = collection.get("date_range");
print ("dates: ", dates)
var daterange = ee.DateRange(dates.get(0), dates.get(1));
print("daterange: ", daterange)
```

This gives an error "dates.get is not a function". However if I create the "dates" variable with...

```
var dates = ee.List(collection.get("date_range"));
```

it all works fine. I don't really understand why this is as the "dates" variable appears to return the same list either way.

Hope someone can explain

Answer (score 1):

I´m having a similar issue. To get the dates I´m using this, maybe it helps you:

```
// Load MODIS EVI imagery.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('NDVI');
var start_date = ee.Date('2020-12-01')
var end_date = fecha_inicio.advance(90, 'days')


var series = collection.filterDate(start_date , 
end_date).map(function(image) {
   return image.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
 });


var dates = series
    .map(function(image) {
    return ee.Feature(null, {'date': image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
    })
   .distinct('date')
   .aggregate_array('date')
   
print('Dates list', dates)
```

My problem is that I can´t acces to the elements in the list, but I obtain a list with the dates I need from the collection

Answer (score 1):

Basically Earth Engine doesn't know the type of objects which you get from `ee.List` and `ee.Dictionary`. So any time you have an error where it says `variable.function is not a function` most of the time it is enough to explicitly cast it to the desired type.

In your case casting `dates` to an `ee.List` would be enough to make it work.

So in your case this would work:

```
//Get date range
var dates = ee.List(collection.get("date_range"));
print ("dates: ", dates)
var daterange = ee.DateRange(dates.get(0), dates.get(1));
print("daterange: ", daterange)
```